# How to add proxy config in angular.json. icannot find the property options?

Tags: angular

i cant add proxy config in **angular.json** and i cannot find options in it.
i tried adding it in **serve/configurations** both in production and development but not working
i am using angular version **15.1.5**

and i even tired starting with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` this is also not working.

and here is my anglular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "blog": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/blog",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "blog:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "blog:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "blog:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

and this is my proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it inside `angular.json` file in the section `architect > serve` like below:

```
"options": {
     "browserTarget": "blog:build",
     "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
}
```

Comment: Not working

`"serve": {
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "blog:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "blog:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "blog:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }`

this is how i added

Comment: Where is your proxy.conf.json file located? Is the address of that file correct?

Comment: in project root. same place where angular.json located